# how do I color all pixels that are NOT transparent to black

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, colormatrixfilter

I am using ColorMatixFilter on an Image in Flex. I am really close to getting want I need out of the filter. Basically any PNG file the user uploads I want all pixels that are not transparent to be colored black. I have a function that sets the "brightness" already so I just through a really large negative number at it like -1000 and it does the job but the problem is any pixels that have any alpha to them, say 0.9 or below all end up being white when I encode my PNG file on the server later.

here is the code I am currently using

```
public static function setBrightness(value:Number):ColorMatrixFilter
    {
        value = value * (255 / 250);

        var m:Array = new Array();
        m = m.concat([1, 0, 0, 0, value]); // red
        m = m.concat([0, 1, 0, 0, value]); // green
        m = m.concat([0, 0, 1, 0, value]); // blue
        m = m.concat([0, 0, 0, 1, 0]); // alpha

        return new ColorMatrixFilter(m);
    }
```

I would like all pixels to be solid black unless the pixel is completely transparent and not sure how to tweak the values to get that out of it.

Comment: I tested the `ColorMatrix`, and it looks correct to me. The problem is likely to do with how you are encoding as png. Many encoders lose the alpha channel in the process. Could you provide more details on that? Also, why not encode on the client? ImageSnapshot can do png encoding.

Comment: Like Jacob Eggers said White is usually the default color when a transparent pixel looses its alpha channel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should take a look at [BitmapData.threshold()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#threshold%28%29) as it does pretty much exactly what you want. Paraphrasing the example on the link you should do something like this:

```
// png is your PNG BitmapData
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(png.width, png.height, true, 0xff000000);
var pt:Point = new Point(0, 0);
var rect:Rectangle = bmd.rect;
var operation:String = "<";
var threshold:uint = 0xff000000;
var color:uint = 0x00000000;
var maskColor:uint = 0xff000000;
bmd.threshold(png, rect, pt, operation, threshold, color, maskColor, true);
```

What we've set up here is a call to `threshold()` that will examine each pixel of `png` and replace the pixel color with with black if the alpha value for that pixel is not 100% (0xff).

In this case `threshold` is `0xff000000` (an [ARGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space) value) which corresponds with black at 100% transparency.  Our mask color is also set to `0xff000000` which tells `threshold()` that we are only interested in the alpha (the 'A' in ARGB) values for each pixel.  Our value for `operation` is "less than" meaning if the pixel value determined by applying `maskColor` is below `threshold` replace it with `color`.